# $0$ section is continuous in étalé definition of sheaf

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Consider the definition of sheaves of abelian group over a topological space $X$ given in Faisceaux Algébriques Cohérents. That is, a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ is given by:

- An abelian group $\mathscr{F}_x$ for each $x \in X$;
- A topology on $\mathscr{F}$, the disjoint union of the $\mathscr{F}_x$;

Satisfying:

1. The projection map $\pi: \mathscr{F} \to X, f \in \mathscr{F}_x \mapsto x$ is a local homeomorphism;
2. The function $f \mapsto -f$ is a continuoun function from $\mathscr{F}$ to $\mathscr{F}$. We denote by $\mathscr{F}+\mathscr{F}$ the subset of $\mathscr{F} \times \mathscr{F}$ of those pairs $(f, g)$ such that $\pi(f) = \pi(g)$. Then the function $(f, g) \mapsto f+g$ is a continuous function from $\mathscr{F}+\mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{F}$.

We define, for an open set $U \subseteq X$, the section $\Gamma(U, \mathscr{F})$ over $U$ as the set of continuous functions $s: U \to \mathscr{F}$ such that $\pi \circ s = id_U$. The article we mentioned says that the axioms 1 and 2 prove that $\Gamma(U, \mathscr{F})$ is an abelian group.  However, it seems to me that first one has to prove that this set is always nonempty (once this is proved, it follows that it is a subgroup of the group of "all sections" - disregarding the continuity of a section). Thus, I want to prove from these axioms that $x \mapsto 0 \in \mathscr{F}_x$ is a continuous function. I don't know exactly how to prove it from the axioms, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\zeta: x \mapsto 0 \in \mathscr{F}_x$ defines a set map, it suffices to show that it is continuous at each $x_0 \in X$. Let $f_0 \in \pi^{-1}(x_0)$. Since $\pi$ is a local homeomorphism at $f_0$, there are neighborhoods $U$ of $f_0$ and $V$ of $x_0$ such that $\pi_U : U \to V$ is a homeomorphism. Let $s : V \to U \to \mathscr{F}$ be its inverse. Denote by $-s$ the composition $(f \mapsto -f) \circ s$. Then $(s, -s)$ defines a continuous map $V \to \mathscr{F} + \mathscr{F}$ and $\zeta|V$ agrees with $((f, g) \mapsto (f + g)) \circ (s, -s)$, which is continuous.